# JQuery dynamic for loop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql

I have a table that has several tables in it for multiple users. These users can increase or decrease overtime, so I am trying to make it as dynamic as possible. I will attach two sample tables so you get the idea.

```
<div class="timecard">
 <h3>tommytest</h3>

<table class="misc_items timecard_list" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="display_row odd">
            <td align="left" class="job_code" style="color:#000099">2400-Orchard</td>
            <td align="right">9:47am</td>
            <td align="right">5/19/2014</td>
            <td align="right" class="hrs">01:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="display_odd row">
            <td align="left" class="job_code" style="color:#000099">1200-Duffy's</td>
            <td align="right">12:37am</td>
            <td align="right">5/17/2014</td>
            <td align="right" class="hrs">2:00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="timecard">
 <h3>testtest</h3>

<table class="misc_items timecard_list" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="display_row odd">
            <td align="left" class="job_code" style="color:#000099">2400-Orchard</td>
            <td align="right">9:47am</td>
            <td align="right">5/19/2014</td>
            <td align="right" class="hrs">01:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="display_odd row">
            <td align="left" class="job_code" style="color:#000099">1200-Duffy's</td>
            <td align="right">12:37am</td>
            <td align="right">5/17/2014</td>
            <td align="right" class="hrs">2:00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="total"></div>
```

I then have this JQuery script that takes the totals from the employees times at the different job codes and totals them up. The script itself is dynamic for each job code, but I am trying to make it dynamic so that it runs through the first table or user, outputs the totals and then does the same for the next tables, so on and so forth.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var timeString = $(this).next('td.hrs').text();
var components = timeString.split(':');
var seconds = components[1] ? parseInt(components[1], 10) : 0;
var hrs = parseInt(components[0], 10) + seconds / 60;
total += hrs;

var temp = [];
$('.job_code').each(function (index, element) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (text != 'Out') {
        temp.push(text);
    }
});

// remove duplicates
var job_code = [];
$.each(temp, function (index, element) {
    if ($.inArray(element, job_code) === -1) job_code.push(element);
});

var sum = {};
$.each(job_code, function (index, element) {
    var total = 0;
    $('.job_code:contains(' + element + ')').each(function (key, value) {
        var timeString = $(this).siblings('td.hrs').text();
        var components = timeString.split(':');
        var seconds = components[1] ? parseInt(components[1], 10) : 0;
        var hrs = parseInt(components[0], 10) + seconds / 60;
        total += hrs;
        sum[index] = {
            'job_code': element,
                'total': total
        };
    });
});

console.log(sum);

$.each(sum, function (index, element) {
    $('#total').append('<p>Total for ' + element.job_code + ': ' + element.total + '</p>');
});

});
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I am just starting to use javascript and am quickly reaching the end of my capabilities. Here is a link to a sample [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ha546/2/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try adding dynamic table to it and run?

Comment: @SSS I tried a little bit of that, but I just posted the dynamic code I have working as I wanted some guidance before heading down the wrong path.

Comment: Just write the calculation code in a callback function and you are good to go. Invoke the function when content added dynamically

Comment: Your design does not seem to allow a per user/table total. How do you want to handler individual user totals?

Comment: @SSS can you show me with a sample jsFiddle?

Comment: @user3558931 what if i make each table have different ids?

Comment: Table IDs would not address my concern which is, if you want a total for each table per your description, shouldn't you have an element in which to put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
  function tfoot(total){
  var tfoot = ['<tfoot>',
         '<tr>',
         '<td colspan="3">Total</td>',
         '<td>'+total+'</td>',
         '</tr>',
         '</tfoot>'];
 return tfoot.join('/n');
 }

$('table').each(function(){
 var sum = 0;
 $(this).find('td.hrs').each(function(){
  sum+= +$(this).text().split(':')[0]
 });
 $(this).append(tfoot(sum));
});
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xenamido/1/edit)**

EDITTED:

```
 function toSeconds(s){
  var p = s.split(':');
  return parseInt(p[0], 10) * 3600 + parseInt(p[1], 10) * 60;
 }

function fill(s, digits) {
 s = s.toString();
 while (s.length < digits) s = '0' + s;
  return s;
 }

function addRows(obj){
 var rows='<tr><td colspan="4">Total:</td></tr>';
 for(var key in obj){
 var formatted = fill(Math.floor(obj[key] / 3600), 2) + ':' +
 fill(Math.floor(obj[key] / 60) % 60, 2); 
  rows+='<tr><td colspan="3">'+key+'</td><td>'+formatted+'</td></tr>';
 } 
return rows;
}

$('table').each(function(){
 var tr = {};
 $(this).find('tr').each(function(){
 var key = $(this).find('td.job_code').text();
 var val1 = toSeconds($(this).find('td.hrs').text());
//var val = +$(this).find('td.hrs').text().split(':')[0];
if(tr[key]){
  tr[key]+=val1;
 }else{
   tr[key]=val1; 
 } 
});

$(this).append(function(){
 var tfoot = $('<tfoot/>', {
 html: addRows(tr)
});
 return tfoot;
});
});
```

**[EDITED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xenamido/5/edit)**

Comment: @mgardner05 not sure if this what you're looking for?

Comment: Extremely close. Instead of totaling all job_codes together. I was hoping it would total each up individually. So say job_code 1 had 3 hours and job_code 2 had 5 hours. Can your code be changed to do that?

Comment: ahh, you want to dynamically create tables and group it by job_code?

Comment: Sort of. If you look at my example jsFiddle you can get a better idea. I was looking for it to run through each table and do what my existing code did for each table, no matter how many there were.

Comment: I was hoping to get the totals under each separate total instead of adding up across all the tables. Does that help?

Comment: @mgardner05: This should do what you want. I've provided the link to the demo below.

Comment: Close, but still not exactly. I am so sorry that my description of my problem was this confusing. I was looking to have it say the totals under each table individually. So under table 1 it'll say 2 hours for duffys 3 hours for orchard. Then under table 2 it'll say 1 hour for duffy's 2.5 hours for orchard. Does that make more sense? I can join a chat if that is easier.

Comment: So you want running totals for each job code under each table?

Comment: Correct total each job code under each table, but do no overall job code to job code or table to table totals are needed.

Comment: Ahh I see, that makes it easier. I think

Comment: @mgardner05: Check it now, I think this is the one. The one all the way on the bottom. Marked as FINAL EDIT.

Comment: That is exactly how it needs to look :) The only thing is it only calculates the 00's in front of the colon and doesn't add the minutes during the totaling.

Comment: So for example it will only add values such as 01:00 or 10:00 but doesn't work with 01:30 or 10:25?

Comment: @mgardner05: I have edited my answer so you should be all set. IF you find my answer useful, please dont forget to mark it useful ;)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for your patience. I will up mark and accept your answer once you update :)